# Rails 4 form_for nested resources issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, erb, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have researched similar questions however I don't feel link they have addressed my particular issue:
[Rails form_for results in POST instead of PUT when trying to edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35189653/rails-form-for-results-in-post-instead-of-put-when-trying-to-edit)

[form_for with nested resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034700/form-for-with-nested-resources)

I'm a novice with Rails (using Rails 4.2.5) an am attempting my first application. My issue is two fold: (1) When a user goes to edit a user story the fields of the form do not populate with previously inputted data (2) When the form is resubmitted, a new entry is created, opposed to editing the old data.

I have a feeling that my form_for for `user_stories/edit.html.erb` is the issue. When I take out the `.build` method from the form I get the following error message:

> undefined method `to_key' for #UserStory::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f456a759138>

The `projects/_form.html.erb` for my project's view does not have the `.build` method and functions correctly. However the only way I can get the `user_stories/_form.html.erb form to work is if I attach the build method.

Here is my code:

*user_story.rb*

```
class UserStory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user

  include RankedModel
  ranks :row_order
end
```

*project.rb*

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_stories 
  belongs_to :user
end
```

*routes.rb*

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
    resources :projects do
      resources :user_stories
    end
  end

  resources :user_stories do
    post :update_row_order, on: :collection
  end

  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

*user_stories/_form.html.erb*

```
<%= form_for([@project, @user_story.build]) do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <p>As a ...</p>
      <%= f.text_field :param1, placeholder: "type of user", class: "form-control"     %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <p>I want ...</p>
      <%= f.text_field :param2, placeholder: "desired functionality", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <p>so that...</p>
      <%= f.text_field :param3, placeholder: "reason for desired functionality", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

*user_stories_controller.rb*

```
class UserStoriesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_project
  before_action :set_user_story, except: [:create]


  def index
    @user_story = @project.user_stories.rank(:row_order).all
  end

  def update_row_order
    @user_story.row_order_position = user_story_params[:row_order_position]
    @user_story.save

    render nothing:true # this is a POST action, updates sent via AJAX, no view   rendered

  end

  def create
    @user_story = @project.user_stories.create(user_story_params)
    redirect_to @project
  end

  def new
  end 

  def destroy
    if @user_story.destroy
      flash[:success] = "User story deleted"
    else
      flash[:error] = "User story could not be deletd"
    end
    redirect_to @project
  end

  def complete
    user_story.update_attribute(completed_at, Time.now)
    redirect_to @project, notice: "User story completed functionality complete"
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.user_stories.update(@project, user_story_params)
        format.html { redirect_to project_path(@project), notice: 'User story was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user_story }

      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user_story.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def edit
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @user_story = @project.user_stories(params[:id])
  end

  def show
  end

private

  def set_project
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  end

  def set_user_story
    @user_story = @project.user_stories(params[:id])
  end

  def user_story_params
    params[:user_story].permit(:param1, :param2, :param3, :row_order_position)
  end
end
```

Comment: I suspect you're getting the error because @user_story is not an instance of UserStory

Answer (score 0):

There are just a few changes needed (tweaks, really), and I'll go through them top-to-bottom.

### 1) `before_action :set_user_story`

This will use the `param[:id]` to find the proper `@user_story` model object and automatically make it available to the proper methods.  In this case it's being `except`ed for `:create`, but should also exclude other methods that don't have an `:id` in the route.  Use this instead:

```
before_action :set_user_story, except: [:index, :new, :create]
```

This will solve (or prevent) some annoying and persistent ActiveRecord failures.

### 2) The `index` action

In this method, the name of the variable is non-standard by Rails naming conventions.  The variable is currently *singular*, but represents a list of UserAction model object, which typically uses a `plural` name.  Use this, instead:

```
def index
  @user_stories = @project.user_stories.rank(:row_order).all
end
```

This change will cause a break in the `app/views/user_stories/index.html.erb` view, where any use of the `@user_story` variable would need to be changed to `@user_stories`.  Keeping with naming conventions has many immediate and long-term benefits, so it's worth making the extra effort to change this to be consistent.

*Note*: the `index` action typically doesn't have a *singular* model object to work with, as this action is used to provide a *list* of the model objects.

### 3) The `new` action

The `new` action is used to create and initialize a new model object for editing.  As the `before_action :set_user_story` is no longer being called for the `new` action, the `@user_story` model object has to be created here.  This code will do that correctly:

```
def new
  @user_story = UserStory.new
  @user_story.project = @project
  # Set other important default values for display now
end
```

And at this point, you should be able to successfully create a new UserStory model object, ready to be edited by the user.

### 4) The `edit` action

As the `before_action :set_user_story` handler is already being called for the `edit` action, there's no need to query for `@user_story` from within the body of the `edit` action; that line can be removed:

```
def edit
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
end
```

This will actually fix the original issue that was reported, as this form of `find` will (unfortunately for this situation) return multiple records, which means that you get a collection back, and not a single record.  This is the actual cause of this error message:

> undefined method `to_key' for #UserStory::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f456a759138>

Assigning the `@user_story` within the `edit` action overwrote the value that had previously been assigned from the `before_action` handler, and replaced it with an improper query result.

### 5) The `complete` action

The `complete` action is a custom *member* action, which means that it depends on the `:id`, just like many of the other actions.  The code is almost correct, except that the `user_story` variable used within the body of the method is actually missing the `@`; this is originally retrieved by the `before_action` handler.

```
def complete
  @user_story.update_attribute(completed_at, Time.now)
  redirect_to @project, notice: "User story completed functionality complete"
end
```

It's likely that this method had not been called yet during testing, as the `edit` action was an upstream test that failed.  This should work when you get to testing this method.

### 6) Teh codez

Changing those few details will finalize the UserStoriesController, which was in pretty great shape to begin with.  Adding in those changes, this is the final controller code:

```
class UserStoriesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_project
  before_action :set_user_story, except: [:index, :new, :create]

  def index
    @user_stories = @project.user_stories.rank(:row_order).all
  end

  def update_row_order
    @user_story.row_order_position = user_story_params[:row_order_position]
    @user_story.save

    render nothing:true # this is a POST action, updates sent via AJAX, no view rendered
  end

  def create
    @user_story = @project.user_stories.create(user_story_params)
    redirect_to @project
  end

  def new
    @user_story = UserStory.new
    @user_story.project = @project
    # Set other important default values for display now
  end 

  def destroy
    if @user_story.destroy
      flash[:success] = "User story deleted"
    else
      flash[:error] = "User story could not be deleted"
    end
    redirect_to @project
  end

  def complete
    @user_story.update_attribute(completed_at, Time.now)
    redirect_to @project, notice: "User story completed functionality complete"
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.user_stories.update(@project, user_story_params)
        format.html { redirect_to project_path(@project), notice: 'User story was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user_story }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user_story.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def edit
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  end

  def show
  end

 private

  def set_project
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  end

  def set_user_story
    @user_story = @project.user_stories(params[:id])
  end

  def user_story_params
    params[:user_story].permit(:param1, :param2, :param3, :row_order_position)
  end
end
```